# VB.net RESTSharp AddFile using stream

Tags: vb.net, restsharp

I am trying to upload a file using RESTSharp in vb.net.

I am not able to complete this.

Following is the code I am trying.

```
Public Function CreateUploadFileRequest(ByVal path As String, ByVal filename As String, ByVal fileStream As Stream) As RestRequest
            Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
            request.Timeout = Integer.MaxValue
            request.Resource = "{version}/files/dropbox{path}"
            request.AddParameter("version", _version, ParameterType.UrlSegment)
            request.AddParameter("path", path, ParameterType.UrlSegment)
            request.AddParameter("file", filename)
            request.AddFile("file", fileStream, filename) '---I am wrong at this line
            Return request
        End Function
```

---

I found C# code, but not able to convert a particular line in vb.net

```
request.AddFile(FieldName, (s) =>
    {
        fileStream.CopyTo(s);
        fileStream.Flush();
    }, FileName, ContentType);
```

If I convert above into vb.net, **then it does not work**. Below is converted code.

```
request.AddFile("file", Function(s)
fileStream.CopyTo(s)
fileStream.Flush()
End Function, FileName, ContentType)
```

---

I also found one more line in c# but same is not working in vb.net after code convert.

```
[in C#] request.AddFile ("file", s => StreamUtils.CopyStream (fileStream, s), filename);
```

Converted to vb.net , **[Not working]**

```
[in vb.net] request.AddFile("file", Function(s) StreamUtils.CopyStream(fileStream, s), filename)
```

Comment: You can simply pass a byte array there, along with the file name. So, `File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)` would do (also in-lined).

Comment: i do not have actual file, one of the other function is generating pdf file into stream, that function does not save that stream into file . So i want to use that pdf stream to upload using RESTSharp

Comment: Read all the bytes from the Stream then.

Comment: i tried that, but I am making mistake somewhere. Can you please share code lines?

Comment: If that is actually a generic Stream, try this: `dim ms as new MemoryStream() fileStream.CopyTo(ms)` then pass the array to the method: `request.AddFile("file", ms.ToArray(), filename) '[...] ms.Dispose()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following is working:**

```
dim ms as new MemoryStream()
request.AddFile("file", ms.ToArray(), "123.pdf_or_whateverfilename")
ms.Dispose()
```

Comment: ms will be filled by the respective function in my code. In my case, it will be written by the pdf generator function.